# React and Redux differences in code that should be used and not used (conceptual)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm working with React-Redux and just wanted a bit of clarification as it is a mental blocker for me.

Using the Redux libraries allows us to have a different architecture to manage state - ok.

But using this comes with a variety of helper functions and in the process of looking at online material I have found there are a number of ways of writing your code.

In terms of state management, Facebook's react docs includes stuff like componentWillMount, componentDidMount, getState, etc. Then there's connect(), Redux thunks, etc.

Is it correct that these should still be used when writing Redux-React? Does it defeat the point in Redux? I'm a little confused at where the line is drawn between the two in terms of how to actually write code?

As always, thank you for the advice

Comment: React is a view presentation layer. Redux is a state management library. The line is your needs.

Comment: For example connect() is from the React-Redux library. Does this mean I should be using it in a react+redux app and not componentWillMount, etc.? Does it matter if I mix the two together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this official Redux tutorial section: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html
That will help you to understand how to use them in pair. Even better, check whole tutorial.

Comment: That's really helpful - I seem to have missed that one on my first read through of the docs. Thanks!